# When using descriptive verbs (형용사), does adding the subject particle 이/가 onto the thing being described make any difference?

Tags: grammar, subject-particle

It seems that 'the thing being described' is the subject of a descriptive verb, so

> 그 여자 예뻐요

basically means the same as

> 그 여자**가** 예뻐요

My question is : Is there *any* difference at all in the meaning, level of formality, or 'feel' of those two utterances, in any context? Or is the 가 always entirely optional and redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"그 여자 예뻐요" can be considered as a shortened form of "그 여자가 예뻐요". Therefore, there is almost no meaning difference (가 is optional).

However, in a formal (and often informal) **writing**, "그 여자가 예쁘다." is far more frequent than "그 여자 예쁘다." In a conversation, either way is OK (both are well used).